# How to visualize callout lines between points and labels in Geoserver?

Tags: qgis, geoserver, sld

Is there a way to visualize calloutlines between points and dynamic labels in Geoerver (SLD)?

From my understanding, there are no elements in TextSymbolizer to achieve it. But perhaps, there is a way to work things around by applying a more advanced SLD-scheme?

Basicly, i wonder if it is possible to convert the vizualisation in the picture below (from Qgis) to an SLD-scheme. Note: the circles are points not polygons.

[image: Calloutlines in Qgis]

Comment: does https://blog.ianturton.com/geoserver/styling/2016/03/15/Leader-lines.html help?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link. It is certanly a candidate for a solution to the problem. However, from my understanding, the labels in the SLD are static, at the end of the lines and do not follow dynamic labels. The quest for that kind of solution is still on i guess...

Answer (score 1):

The rendering engine in GeoServer cannot do callouts. It can happen, just needs someone to either [contribute their time](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/main/CONTRIBUTING.md) to the rendering engine, found in GeoTools, or [sponsor a developer](http://geoserver.org/comm/) to do it on their behalf.

Comment: ok and no creative way of working around it? Using perhaps Filter Function or line layers (like proposed above)?